# Typescript: Add Event Listener overloads to child class

Tags: typescript, inheritance, event-listener, eventemitter

I have a parent class like this:

```js
interface A extends EventEmitter{
    on(event: "eventA", listener: () => void): this;
}
```

and another class like this:

```js
interface B extends A{
    on(event: "eventB", listener: () => void): this;
}
```

I want to use this like this:

```js
const foo = new B();
foo.on("eventA", listenerForA);
foo.on("eventB", listenerForB);
```

Changing anything in A is not possible.

Implementing it like this throws an Error: `TS2415: Class 'B' incorrectly extends 'A'`

PS: you also need to declare class A and class B, but for clarity I removed these.

[view code in TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECiBuBTAdgF1gWwJatYgTgN4BQ0Z0A9sgBSJJoBc0Eq+WyA5gDTQhYsoCTagEpoAXgB80eBSwATEUzDIAniXKbopcgF9i+0JBgBBaIgAeeZPJgIU6bLgIkDxI1GgAhV-vZ58ADMwYERoM0trWzh6RxwAjXIqWlimACI6BxM0nj4BZCFoUQlpWQUlaFQAC34Abjd-AmDQ73MrFGiTRLJkzMZoDNivHN5+a0LiqRk5RSZqurd3KhZoQIoKCWgCgHdvUXq1igA6ZMGsnMnpQl0RA-WTmjO0Ya5L6GvboA)

Edit: it helps to copy the overloads from the parent class. But is there another way to do this without duplicating the overloads?

Thank you for everything that could help in any way.

Comment: You have to make the subclass a true overload by providing both call signatures, but: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/weXVEW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Thank you for the VERY fast answer. It is my first question on stackoverflow, thank you for the tips. It helped to copy the overloads from the parent class.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the answer from Фарид Ахмедов, I have coded this, which also works for callback overloads:

```
interface B extends A{
    on(event: Parameters<A['on']>[0], listener: Parameters<A['on']>[1]): this;
    on(event: "eventB", listener: (bar: string) => void): this;
}
```

The first overload copies the previous overloads.

Using `Parameters<...>` you could also add all overloads for `EventEmitter.emit()`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe like that:

```js
// Get `on` first parameter type
type EventFrom<T extends A> = Parameters<T['on']>[0]

interface A {
    on(event: "eventA"): this;
}

interface B extends A {
    on(event: "eventB" | EventFrom<A>): this; // eventA | eventB
}

interface C extends B {
    on(event: "eventC" | EventFrom<B>): this; // eventA | eventB | eventC
}
```

Comment: one problem: this uses only the last overload